# C++ static member functions and variables

Tags: c++

I am learning C++ by making a small robot simulation and I'm having trouble with static member functions inside classes.

I have my Environment class defined like this:

```
class Environment {
    private:
        int numOfRobots;
        int numOfObstacles;

        static void display(); // Displays all initialized objects on the screen

    public:
        Robot *robots;
        Obstacle *obstacles;

        // constructor
        Environment();

        static void processKeySpecialUp(int, int, int); // Processes the keyboard events
};
```

Then in the constructor I initialize the robots and obstacles like this:

```
numOfRobots = 1; // How many robots to draw
numOfObstacles = 1;
robots = new Robot[numOfRobots];
obstacles = new Obstacle[numOfObstacles];
```

Here is example of static function that uses those variables:

```
void Environment::display(void) {
    // Draw all robots
    for (int i=0; i<numOfRobots; i++) {
        robots[i].draw();
    }
}
```

When I try to compile, I get error messages like

```
error: invalid use of member ‘Environment::robots’ in static member function
```

I tried making numOfRobots, numOfObstacles, robots and obstacles **static**, but then I got errors like

```
error: undefined reference to 'Environment::numOfRobots'
```

I would greatly appreciate of someone could explain me what I am doing wrong.
Thank you!

Comment: In the static version of your code you are failing to define `Environment::numOfRobots`, you have only declared it. Add `int Environment::numOfRobots = 1;` to one of your source files. A book on C++ will explain how to declare and define variables along with much other essential information.

Comment: Since you said you are learning C++, might I suggest using the standard library? Specifically an `std::vector` instead of raw arrays.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Static methods can't use non-static variables from its class.

That's because a static method can be called like `Environment::display()` without a class instance, which makes any non-static variable used inside of it, irregular, that is, they don't have a parent object.

You should consider why you are trying to use a static member for this purpose. Basically, one example of how a static method can be used is as such:

```
class Environment
{
private:
    static int maxRobots;
public:
    static void setMaxRobots(int max)
    {
        maxRobots = max;
    }
    void printMaxRobots();
};

void Environment::printMaxRobots()
{
    std::cout << maxRobots;
}
```

And you would have to initialize on the global scope the variables, like:

```
int Environment::maxRobots = 0;
```

Then, inside `main` for example, you could use:

```
Environment::setMaxRobots(5);

Environment *env = new Environment;
env->printMaxRobots();
delete env;
```

Comment: Do you have an idea of how can this be fixed? I tried making those variables static, but I was getting errors (please, see the second part of my question)...

Comment: You have to initialize the static variables, see [Static Member Functions](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr039.htm).

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 issues here - the algorithm you're trying to implement and the mechanics of why it won't compile.

Why it doesn't compile.

You're mixing static and instance variables/methods - which is fine. But you can't refer to an instance variable from within a static method. That's the "invalid use" error. If you think about it, it makes sense. There is only one "static void display()" method. So if it tries to refer to the non-static (instance) variable "robots", which one is it referring to? There could be 10 ... or none.

The logic you are trying to implement.

It looks like you want a single Environment class that manages N robots. That's perfectly logical. One common approach is to make Environment a 'singleton' - an instance variable that only allows for a single instance. Then it could allocate as many robots as it want and refer to them freely because there are no static variables/methods.

Another approach is to just go ahead and make the entire Environment class static. Then keep a (static) list of robots. But I think most people these days would say option #1 is the way to go.

Comment: @user1739770 This simple answer is you have a static method that returns a pointer to your class; if there isn't one, it creates it and returns it, otherwise it returns a pointer to the existing one. That way you have an 'instance' class, but never get more than one copy of it. In practice it gets kinda sticky though: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern.

Answer (score 2):

`static` members are those that using them require no instantiation, so they don't have `this`, since `this` require instantiation:

```
class foo {
public
    void test() {
        n = 10; // this is actually this->n = 10
    }
    static void static_test() {
        n = 10; // error, since we don't have a this in static function
    }
private:
    int n;
};
```

As you see you can't call an instance function or use an instance member inside an `static` function. So a function should be static if its operation do not depend on instance and if you require an action in your function that require `this`, you must think why I call this function `static` while it require `this`.

A member variable is `static` if it should shared between all instances of a `class` and it does not belong to any specific `class` instance, for example I may want to have a counter of created instances of my class:

```
// with_counter.h
class with_counter {
private:
    static int counter; // This is just declaration of my variable
public:
    with_counter() {++counter;}
    ~with_counter() {--counter;}

    static int alive_instances() {
        // this action require no instance, so it can be static
        return counter;
    }
};

// with_counter.cpp
int with_counter::counter = 0; // instantiate static member and initialize it here
```

Answer (score 2):

The first error says that you cannot use non-static members in static member functions.

The second one says that you need to *define* static members in addition to *declaring* them You must define static member variables *outside* of a class, in a source file (not in the header) like this:

```
int Environment::numOfRobots = 0;
```

You don't need any static members. To have an absolutely correct and portable GLUT interface, have a file-level object of type `Environment` and a file-level (non-member) function declared with C linkage. For convenience, have also a member function named `display`.

```
class Environment 
{
 public:
   void display() { ... }
   ... 
};

static Environment env;
extern "C" void display () { env.display(); }
```

Answer (score 1):

A static member function is one that can be called without an actual object of that kind. However, your function `Environment::display` uses the variables `numOfRobots` and `robots`, which both live in a particular instance of the `Environment` class. Either make `display` non-static (why do you want it to be static?) or make the robots static members of `Environment` too.

In your case, I don't see a reason for making `display` or `processKeySpecialUp` `static`, so just make them normal member functions. If you wonder when a member function should be `static`, consider if that function would make sense if no objects of that class have been created (i.e. no constructors been called). If the function doesn't make sense in this context, then it shouldn't be `static`.

Comment: I am using Glut library to handle the graphics and I need to keep the display static. And as I said before, i tried making those variables static, but I was getting error: undefined reference to 'Environment::numOfRobots'

Answer (score 0):

A static method cannot access instance variables. If you want to access instance variable remove static from the method. If those values can be the same through all robot instances then make them static variables and the method can remain static.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to access member variables in static member function just create a static pointer of the member variable and use it in the function !!!!!