# Getting error "a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object" while both member are in the same class

Tags: c++, class, static, ros

I know this question had been asked many times but I'm still stuck. I thought I got what this error was about what obviously I don't.

So, the error I am getting is

```
a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object
```

My code is:

```
class theTranslator {
public:
    ros::NodeHandle nh;

    ros::Publisher pub = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::Image>("camera/depth/image_raw", 100);

    static void getMessage(const sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr& recMmsg) {
        ROS_INFO( "I heard message" );
        pub.publish(recMmsg); //*** ERROR IS HERE ***
    }
};
```

since `pub` is part of the same class as `getMessage()`, shouldn't it work? How can I make a `static` member function use a variable member of the same class?

P.S. this is done in *ROS* (Robotics Operating System) but I believe this is a C++ mistake (not related to ROS).

Comment: How would the compiler know which object's pub member to use? You have to send in e.g. a pointer or reference to an actual theTranslator object as a param to getMessage, and access the pub member of that instance. But normally, static member fcns access only static data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++ you can not access a non static class member from a static method. Make it a normal method and try like below:-

```
 void getMessage(const sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr& recMmsg){
        ROS_INFO( "I heard message" );
        pub.publish(recMmsg); //*** ERROR IS HERE ***
    }
```

Else declare pub as static member

```
static ros::Publisher pub;
```

Also refer to the below answer

[C++ static member functions and variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13203999/c-static-member-functions-and-variables)

Comment: well that sucks. I thought if the are in the same class, it is correct. With my current design, I can't do what you suggest. Back to the whiteboard I guess. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make `getMessage` non-static or you need to make `pub` static.

Probably what you really need to do is rethink your design. Why are you trying to make `getMessage` static? As a very general rule of thumb static is a mistake, especially for a newbie.

Comment: It is related to how ROS handles message transmission between nodes. You are right, I need to redesign my code. Thanks.

Comment: @DimitrisPantelis Usually the motivation for making a member function static is because you need to use it as a callback. It's a well known problem, how to get from a callback function to an object. Some googling will probably help.

Comment: actually that is what I want, use it as a callback. will google it.